# Minimizing shuffle when mapper output is mostly sorted

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a map-reduce process in which the mapper takes input from a file that is sorted by key. For example:

```
1 ...
2 ...
2 ...
3 ...
3 ...
3 ...
4 ...
```

Then it gets transformed and 99.9% of the keys stay in the same order in relation to one another and 99% of the remainder are close. So the following might be the output of running the map task on the above data:

```
a ...
c ...
c ...
d ...
e ...
d ...
e ...
```

Thus, if you could make sure that a reducer took in a range of inputs and put that reducer in the same node where most of the inputs were already located, the shuffle would require very little data transfer. For example, suppose that I partitioned the data so that a-d were taken care of by one reducer and e-g by the next. Then if a-d could be run on the same node that had handled the mapping of 1-4, only two records for e would need to be sent over the network.

How do I construct a system that takes advantage of this property of my data? I have both Hadoop and Spark available and do not mind writing custom partitioners and the like. However, the full workload is such a classic example of MapReduce that I'd like to stick with a framework which supports that paradigm.

[Hadoop mail archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-mapreduce-user/201006.mbox/%3CAANLkTimK0_h8pILPYagnRmAQPGPsvBCZdNklaDudUX0Y@mail.gmail.com%3E) mention consideraton of such an optimization. Would one need to modify the framework itself to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the *SPARK* perspective there is not direct support for this: the closest is *mapPartitions* with *preservePartions=true*.  However that will not directly help in your case because the keys may not be changed.

```
  /**
   * Return a new RDD by applying a function to each partition of this RDD.
   *
   * `preservesPartitioning` indicates whether the input function preserves the partitioner, which
   * should be `false` unless this is a pair RDD and the input function doesn't modify the keys.
   */
  def mapPartitions[U: ClassTag](
      f: Iterator[T] => Iterator[U], preservesPartitioning: Boolean = false): RDD[U] = {
    val func = (context: TaskContext, index: Int, iter: Iterator[T]) => f(iter)
    new MapPartitionsRDD(this, sc.clean(func), preservesPartitioning)
  }
```

If you were able to know definitively that none of the keys would move outside of their original partitions the above would work. But the values on the boundaries would likely not cooperate.

What is the scale of the data compared to the migrating keys?  You may consider adding a postprocessing step. First construct a partition for all migrating keys. Your mapper would output a special key value for keys needing to migrate.  Then postprocess the results to do some sort of append to the standard partitions.  That is extra hassle so you would need to evaluate the tradeoff in an extra step and pipeline complexity.

Comment: I am thinking of writing a mapPartitions that extracts an approximate range for each partition, then transforming the ends of the ranges, then using this as a new partitioner that gets applied after a doing the real map step. The new partitioner ensures that most entries will be assigned the same partition number and I hope that means they will not move.

Comment: Yes that would be along the lines of what I was saying. Let us know how that goes for you.

Comment: The partitionBy function creates a shuffle-dependency, so this doesn't work directly. 

If we decide to use this optimization in production, I will write a FilteredByPartitionerRDD class that eliminates those things that do not map to the right partition. Then, I will take the eliminated set, apply the partitioner (they will all be shuffled - but that is unavoidable) and do a union that preserves the partitioning (not sure if I'll have to write this too). Finally a group-by within partitions.